# catch subprocess output spawned by imported module

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

Note: I am aware that I can catch `subprocess` output using `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`.

In my case the `subprocess` will be launched by imported module, for example `youtube-dl` will launch a `subprocess` for `ffmpeg` and I want to catch `ffmpeg` output.

I made a dummy working scenario to make my point clear.

I have 2 files: m1.py "my module" and m2.py "imported library"

m2.py

```
import subprocess
def run():
    print('m2 module message will be caught by echo function too')
    cmd = ['ping', 'google.com']
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

m1.py

```
import sys
import m2

# this is a redirection function to echo stdout to a file
def echo(text):
    with open('out.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(text)

    sys.stdout.write = original
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.write = echo

original = sys.stdout.write
sys.stdout.write = echo

print('m1 module message will be caught by echo function')
m2.run()
```

Terminal output:

```
m1 module message will be caught by echo function
m2 module message will be caught by echo function too

Pinging google.com [172.217.18.46] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.217.18.46: bytes=32 time=86ms TTL=53
Reply from 172.217.18.46: bytes=32 time=78ms TTL=53
```

out.txt

```
m1 module message will be caught by echo function
m2 module message will be caught by echo function too
```

from above it is clear that out.txt file received the 2 print statement from both modules but can't get other output

Question here, how can i get output of "ping" command launched by m2.py, "for sure i can't change code of m2.py because it is a 3rd party library and it is updated weekly"

Answer (score 1):

Note: This may only be a partial response, because it's operation system low level. It worked for me on linux, but I cannot give a statement regarding windows or other os

The attempt with redirecting the output with your `echo()` function doesn't work because this is only overriding `write` in your python process.
The `ping` command (or whatever command is launched by your 3rd party module) is a new process that doesn't inherit your python environment, in particular not the rewritten `write()` function.

But - when spawning a new process it does inherit the stdout filehandle (and I mean the low level os file handle, which is 1 for stdout on unix)

I could redirect your ping output with the following code.

```
import os

...
out2 = open('out2.txt', 'w')
fd = out2.fileno()  # here you get the low level file handle of the new file obj
os.dup2(fd, 1)      # here you are closing your stdout handle and setting it to out2

...
m2.run()     # the spawned ping command is now writing to out2
```

Now this is redirecting to a file object.
I understand you want to read the output in your program.

To achieve that you can create a pipe in python and use that filehandle instead:

```
pipein, pipeout = os.pipe()
```

Note pipein,pipeout are already low level file handles. To use one of them like a python file object you can create one with `os.fdopen(fd)`

Comment: it looks promising, just tested same code on windows and got all output collected in out2.txt, as you said i just need to echo the output to use it for a gui, so i will check os.pipe() and let you know the results

Answer (score 0):

Just return the result of the `subprocess` run and assign it normally

m2

```
import subprocess
def run():
    print('m2 module message will be caught by echo function too')
    cmd = ['ping', 'google.com']
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

m1

```
import sys
import m2

# this is a redirection function to echo stdout to a file
def echo(text):
    with open('out.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(text)

    sys.stdout.write = original
    sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.write = echo

original = sys.stdout.write
sys.stdout.write = echo

print('m1 module message will be caught by echo function')
process_object = m2.run()
output, err = process_object.communicate()
print(output, err)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately, I can't change any code in imported module m2.py, it is a 3rd party library, but i tried your code out of curiosity it throw an error `TypeError: 'Popen' object is not iterable`

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add `communicate()`. That's what gives the output an error. I have made corrections to my answer. If you are certain that the subprocess object is being return from the `m2` module then this should work

Comment: No,  the subprocess object is not being return from the m2 module, thanks anyway